# .load() doesn't include jquery effects

Tags: jquery

I am creating a phonegap application and want to keep a separate html file (_nav.html) for navigation and call it in the main files using the `.load()`

I have successfully done this however, the dropdown in the menu is no longer working.

Do I also need to include the Jquery Files in _nav.html file for the drop down to be working?

I went through [this](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and also [searched it on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.load%28%29%20) however could not get a answer.

***Note: There are no errors in console.***

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT:**
Link: http://nikhilclasses.com/ok/
Link to Nav: view-source:http://nikhilclasses.com/ok/external/_navigation.html

Comment: How, without code?

Comment: Link added for you to refer the code.. thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely because the scripts in your _nav.html are being stripped out by JQuery. As per documentation of **.load()**:

> **Script Execution**
>
> When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector
>   expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being
>   removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If
>   .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL,
>   however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated,
>   and thus are not executed. An example of both cases can be seen below:
>
> Here, any JavaScript loaded into #a as a part of the document will
>   successfully execute.
>
> `$( "#a" ).load( "article.html" );`
>
> However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being
>   loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:
>
> `$( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );`

Source: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks Albert, however am using the first method of execution. Do I need to include all the Jquery in _nav.html too?

Comment: I think not. But you may try to use a callback function to reactive your dropdown after it was loaded in the DOM.

Comment: Ok Albert will try that; I have also updated the links. If you can make out something from it. Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Got a solution. Sharing it here for anyone having the same problem** I had to include the javascript codes inside the _navigation.html file at the bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.deploy-sidebar').click(function(){
    //$(this).toggleClass('remove-sidebar');
    if( snapper.state().state=="left" ){
      snapper.close();
    } else {
      snapper.open('left');
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

The included HTML file was failing to read the query from the parent file and thus the issue. Once the Jquery was included in the bottom. All the functions with the menu started working.